# Incremental AspectJ Compile Time Weaving with Gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, aspectj

I've been working on porting my companies Maven build over to Gradle.
I've got most of it working including aspectj compilation using the [eveoh/gradle-aspectj plugin](https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj).

However, the aspectj compiler is incredibly slow running in our build.
I know that IntelliJ uses some sort of incremental compilation of AspectJ code.

The [AspectJ compiler supports incremental compilation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/bytecode-concepts.html).
But I don't think that this flag will work out of the box with the plugin as is.

The [gradle java plugin supports incremental compiling](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:incremental).

In order to support this the code uses this thing called the [IncrementalCompilerFactory](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/0610a60e6e18d553444dda8324c39df423f244c1/subprojects/language-java/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/compile/incremental/IncrementalCompilerFactory.java) which is a pretty complicated object.

I'm wondering if anyone has figured out how to do incremental compiling with aspectJ in gradle and if there is any example code out there to solve this problem.

Comment: I never used _Gradle_ before, I only know _AspectJ Maven_ and _ajc_ itself. As you are just porting the code from Maven, was incremental compilation working there and was it faster? Or are you just mixing up refactoring with extending/improving the build logic? ;-) If it was better with _AspectJ Maven_, maybe you could check the plugin's source code and see how it calls the AJ compiler.

Comment: One more thing: Incremental compilation for aspect code is not so easy because a minimal change in an aspect can affect thousands of classes depending on the pointcut. Also a pure Java class change can affect many other classes if e.g. it is used by `declare parents`. We are talking about **cross-cutting concerns** here. Anyway, you can have an incremental compiler process running in the background all the time, as it seems. _ajc_'s command line help says: `-incremental: continuously-running compiler, needs -sourceroots (reads stdin: enter to recompile and 'q' to quit)`